# Rails 4 namespaced model not extending ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've generated a model in my app called Twitter::Tweet, it's defined in `app/models/twitter/tweet.rb` as follows:

```
class Twitter::Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

The generator also created a file in `app/models/twitter.rb` as follows:

```
module Twitter
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'twitter_'
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, whenever I try to call `Twitter::Tweet.find` I get a `undefined method "find" for Twitter::Tweet:Class` error.  This also happens when I try `::Twitter::Tweet.find`.  This is my first time working with Namespaced models, and for the life of me I can't figure out how to get them to work properly.  Any ideas before I give up on them and just move on?

Here's the `tweet_controller.rb`

```
class Twitter::TweetsController < Twitter::BaseController
  def show
    @tweet = Twitter::Tweet.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Stack Trace

```
app/controllers/twitter/tweets_controller.rb:3:in `setup'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
/Users/ryan/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:155:in `handle'
/Users/ryan/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:109:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in start'
/Users/ryan/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in start'
/Users/ryan/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:96:in `each'
/Users/ryan/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:96:in `block in start'
/Users/ryan/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:76:in `loop'
/Users/ryan/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:76:in `start'
/Users/ryan/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:12:in `run'
/Users/ryan/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/bin/nack_worker:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you run the `rake db:migrate`? Please, show the full stacktrace.

Comment: Your stack trace generated from tweets_controller.rb(3). You should show the tweets_controller'r related code.

Comment: Change it to: `module Twitter class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
end end` instead and try?

Comment: what's happened if you take a look in database? I mean, is you table named as "twitter_tweets" ?

Comment: @User089247I've tried it both ways, no change

Comment: @MarkoKrstic the table is `twitter_tweets`

Comment: @Masud I've added the controller.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you controller should be under `app/controllers/twitter/tweets_controller.rb` and should look like

```
class Twitter::TweetsController < ApplicationController # maybe you have some problem in Twitter::BaseController
    def show
        @tweet = ::Twitter::Tweet.find(params[:id])
    end
end


#routes.rb:
namespace :twitter do
    resources :tweets
end

#app/views/twitter/tweets/show.html.erb:
<%= @tweet.title %> # or whatever
```

and you get that page with: `http://lvh.me:3000/twitter/tweets/1`

and that should work. (your models are ok)